# Python subprocess.call fails on windows without shell=True

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd, subprocess

I am using `Python 2.7.14` on windows 10 64bit. I need to use

> subprocess.call

but it is failing everytime if I will not pass **shell=True**. As per the [python doc](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html), **shell=True** should not be used. Also I want to know why it is failing.

```
python
ActivePython 2.7.14.2717 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.14 (default, Dec 15 2017, 16:31:45) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['date'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 168, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 390, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 640, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

But when run with shell=True, it is running fine

```
>>> subprocess.call(['date'],shell=True)
The current date is: Wed 12/04/2019
Enter the new date: (mm-dd-yy)
```

I tried on mac too and subprocess.call is running fine without **shell=True**

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

`date` is not an executable, but a [builtin function of cmd.exe](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-internal.html). You cannot use it outside the shell.